# Office application on ubuntu phone

Tags: software-recommendation, ubuntu-touch

What will be the default office app on ubuntu, is it Libreoffice?

Besides, what could be the common apps for phone and PC?

is it possible to port them to phone without reprogramming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu Touch don't (currently) have an office app in the core-apps nor have anyone created one that I know of. The Ubuntu phone uses QT so if you want to port one then the easiest would be to port/fork one that is written in QT - but a lot of work will still be required to get it to work with the screen size.

Since the phone uses QT you won't be able to install Libre, so Libre will not be the default.